# What is the purpose of `NativeLibs` element in csproj file

Tags: c#, .net-core

Recently, when reviewing csproj files, I have seen lot of elements `<NativeLibs Remove="some file" />`

It usually appears if I create and then rename it. But what purpose it serves exactly? Element name suggest that it has something to do with libraries, but it only got me confused.

If I remove it, nothing bad happens, output dir is just fine and I can run my app.

Tried to search the web, but did not find anything usefyl.

Comment: They might be added by some 3rd party Nuget packages